# Multi-Valued Auto-Complete Field

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm new of vaadin and now I'm developing my first application. Now I need to a component like this [Multi-Valued Auto-Complete Field](http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/gwt-rest-auto/). Is there an add-on or something else that could help me to make this component?

I found the following add-on but seems not supported from vaadin7 [SuggestionTextField](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/suggestiontextfield)

Otherwise, can you give me some suggestion about this problem?

**UPDATE1**

I need to **TextChangeListener** because I don't want load all objects in my component, but I want select them when the user insert the values. Now i try to add a textChangeListener in myComboBox:

```
public class SuggestComboBox extends ComboBox{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void changeVariables(Object source, Map<String, Object> variables) {
        if (variables.containsKey("filter")) {
            final String text = variables.get("filter").toString();
            fireEvent(new TextChangeEvent(this) {

                @Override
                public String getText() {
                    return text;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCursorPosition() {
                    return text.length();
                }


            });
        }
        super.changeVariables(source, variables);
    }

    public void addListener(TextChangeListener listener) {

        addListener(TextChangeListener.EVENT_ID, TextChangeEvent.class,
                listener, TextChangeListener.EVENT_METHOD);
    }

    public void removeListener(TextChangeListener listener) {
        removeListener(TextChangeListener.EVENT_ID, TextChangeEvent.class,
                listener);
    }

}
```

but I'm not albe to set the lenght of the pause after which the trigger event.
How Can I do this?

Comment: Hi Skizzo, I need "Multi-Valued Auto-Complete Field" for my Vaadin project as well. Did you find any component or implement yours? will you be able to share your implementation? Thank you in advance...

Comment: Hi Skizzo, I also need that component too. Would be great if you can share yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple ComboBox Component for this if you do not need lazy loading.